Short story about a boy living on a fake tropical island / paradise planet, who was actually an adult CEO but didn't remember it
I've come to my wits end. I read a sci-fi short story back in the 90's as a part of anthology. Unfortunately I can't remember the author, the title, or the collection.
It was about a boy living on a fake tropical island / paradise planet and then a woman came to get him out from there since he was actually an adult CEO of the company (or such) but didn't remember it. Actually he was there on a holiday.
Basically the story can be from anywhere from 90's to back. Not much to go on but any help is appreciated.

"Fake" as in VR or as in physically constructed?

Physically constructed as far as I remember.

This sounds like a story I remember reading in one of Dozois' Best SF of the Year Anthologies -- can't remember which one though -- will need to wait until I can access the books to look it up.

@cybernetic.nomad it was in the Dozois anthology "The Good Stuff"

Psychologically, what's the point of taking a break from a job that you don't remember?

@OrganicMarble must have confused the anthology titles, at least I had the editor right :)

This reminds me somewhat of that time Arthur Dent met the ruler of the universe.

This is likely to be the 1977 story "Good-bye, Robinson Crusoe" by John Varley.
It contains the element of the boy living in a simulated tropical paradise (one of the small-d "disneylands" common to Varley's Eight Worlds stories) and being recalled by a woman because he is actually older and his expertise is needed (in this case, because of a financial crisis caused by speed-of-light effects on currency transactions to Pluto).

"You came here for a vacation. You were going to spend 10 years,
growing up and taking it easy. That's all over. The situation that
prevailed when you left is now out of date...The Common Market of the
Inner Planets has fired the first shot."

It can be read at the Internet Archive, tip o' the hat to DavidW for the link.

Ah, yes.  That's definitely the one.

Story link: https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v01n01_1977-Spring/page/n8/mode/1up
